# Solution to a simple system of quadratic equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations, quadratics, quadratic-forms

I am hoping to find a closed-form solution to the following system of $n$ quadratic equations:

$$ x_j^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n B_{ij}x_i $$

for $j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, where $B_{ij}\geq 0$. There is a trivial solution at $x=0$ but I am looking for others. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I can see how it works for $n=1.$ What happens for $n=2?$

Comment: Yes, for $n=1$ we simply have $x=B$. For $n=2$, it can also be solved by hand: isolate $x_1$ in the first equation and put it in the second one. I'm hoping to find a systematic way of solving the general case. It feels likes some clever matrix algebra could work.

Comment: I guess it's worth noting that, since we're dealing with $n$ linearly independent quadratic equations, there will be $2^n$ solutions (over the complex numbers, counting multiplicities).

Comment: @EinarRødland Yes, I guess I'm mostly interested in strictly positive solutions.

Comment: An algebraic solution would have to work also for general complex solutions, not only non-negative real solutions, so I suspect that would be hard. On the other hand, if $B_{ij}>0$ (or some weaker positivity criterion), I suspect there is a unique strictly positive solution.

Comment: @EinarRødland I agree. If we raise both sides of the equation to power 1/2 we have a concave mapping. The contraction mapping theorem guarantees a unique positive solution. It also gives a way to find the solution: guess a vector $x^0$ compute the RHS (raised to power 1/2) to find a new $x^1$ and keep going until convergence. It works very fast numerically.

Answer (score -2):

Let $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ a matrix with entries $B_{ij}$. Let $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, define $y=(x_1^2,\ldots,x_n^2)$ and note that your system is equivalent to the system $B^Tx = y$. This is a linear system and there is a lot about this in the literature.

Comment: I know how to solve $B^{T}x=y$ when $B$ and $y$ are known but here $y$ is also unknown. If $B^T$ is invertible I get $x=\left(B^T\right)^{-1}y$ but this is still not a solution. Any idea about the next steps?

Comment: You are right about that. I was thinking in solving the system treating $y$ as known, get the solution $x$ (which will depend on the entries $y_i$ of $y$) and substitute $y_i$ for $x_i^2$. I'm not sure if this will change the problem to an easier one, bit this is what I thought.

Comment: Write $y(x)$ just to make clear that $y$ depends on $x$. Maybe there is a way to rewrite the system $B^Tx=y(x)$ and still have some easy system to handle. I'll have to think about it.